# Result not ready when used, works in debugger but not in runtime

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In the following image you can see where i put the breakpoint and then debugged two step. You can also see that both assignments worked great they have the same count and are the same.

[image: This works]

However if I do the following. Run the *exact* same call but only break on the third line directly then this happnes

[image: This does NOT work]

set.QuestionSet.Questions should have count of 8 BEFORE the assigment, so it seems it's not properly assigned for some reason. I suspect this has something to do with how I fetch my data from DB.

Question and QuestionSet are normal POCOs and here is the code for the entire method.

```
    public IEnumerable<QuestionSet> SearchAndFilterQuestionsAndSets(string searchString, int nrPerPage, int page, out int totalSearchCount)
    {
        searchString = searchString.ToLower();
        List<QuestionSet> finalList = new List<QuestionSet>();

        var result = ActiveContext.QuestionSets
        .Select(x => new
        {
            QuestionSet = x,
            Questions = x.Questions.Where(
                y =>
                    y.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchString)
            ).OrderBy(
                z => z.Description
            )
        })
        .ToList();

        foreach (var set in result)
        {
            //If our search matched the set itself we load all questions
            if (set.QuestionSet.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString))
            {
                //we dont bring empty sets
                if (set.QuestionSet.Questions.Count() > 0)
                {
                    set.QuestionSet.Questions = set.QuestionSet.Questions.ToList<Question>().OrderBy(x => x.Description).ToList<Question>();
                    finalList.Add(set.QuestionSet);
                }
            }
            //We had one or more questions matching the search term
            else if (set.Questions.Count() > 0)
            {
                var b = set.Questions.ToList<Question>();
                set.QuestionSet.Questions = set.Questions.ToList<Question>();
                finalList.Add(set.QuestionSet);
            }
        }

        totalSearchCount = finalList.Count();
        return finalList.Skip((page - 1) * nrPerPage).Take(nrPerPage);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If I do this instead in the failing else if

```
var a = new QuestionSet();
a.Id = set.QuestionSet.Id;
a.Name = set.QuestionSet.Name;
a.Questions = set.Questions.ToList<Question>();
finalList.Add(a);
```

Then it works, so the problem lies within the anonymous object, but why does it work when i step through with debugger and not otherwise?? call me puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with Late binding of anonymous types

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but why would it bind late. makes writing good code hard. And do notice with my fix i copy the values off the anonymous type. So all values are in anonymous type actually.